# C# Color mismatches even if its the same

Tags: c#, mismatch

In my program I have:

A color array named "colors" which contains color white rgba(255,255,255,255)

A color named "thecolor with rgba(255,255,255,255)

When I create an if statement like:

```
if (colors.Contains(thecolor)){Console.WriteLine("yes");}
```

The if statement always returns false which should not be the case since colors does contain a color with rgba(255,255,255,255)

I tried outputting both colors with the console:

```
Console.WriteLine(thecolor);
```

> Color [A=255, R=255, G=255, B=255]

```
Console.WriteLine(colors[0]);
```

> Color [White]

Can I make .Contains recognize the colors?

I know I can make a foreach that compares the rgba values, but I want to use .Contains if possible.

Also the color array is created by Newtonsoft's Json parser.

Comment: Could you share the type of object that you are using for color? (including namespace)

Comment: You can create an extension method on the Color type and use.

Comment: `Enumerable.Contains` accepts an `IEqualityComparer`. Implementing a proper `IEqualityComparer<Color>` would alleviate this. If you're going to do a lot of `.Contains` checks on possibly big collections, storing things in a `HashSet` would speed things up, and `HashSet` accepts a comparer in its constructor, so you wouldn't even need to parameterize `.Contains`.

Comment: As mentioned by @Greg, the 'named color White' is not equal to 'the color with rgba(255,255,255,255)'

Comment: This has nothing to do with colors. This has to do with objects. "thecolor" is not the same object as the color[white] object in your array. Since colors.Contains() does nothing else than running `object.Equals(thecolor)` for each element, it won't find it. You have no other chance than comparing the properties or implementing an `IEqualityComparer`.

Comment: Well, you cannot rely on framework's equality comparer to behave on your terms. Create and use your own equality comparer.

Comment: https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.collections.icomparer(v=vs.110).aspx

Comment: To compare colors for equality always use their ToArgb values!